# java.util.ArrayList loop through rest elements inside a loop

Tags: java

Given a non-empty ArrayList, what's the most elegant way to loop through rest elements while iterating that list ?

```
Give an ArrayList instance 'exampleList' contains five strings: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

while looping through it:

```
for(String s : exampleList){
 // when s is "A", I want to loop through "B"-"E", inside this loop
 // when s is "B", I want to loop through "C"-"E", inside this loop
 // when s is "C", I want to loop through "D"-"E", inside this loop
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way would probably be using the traditional for loop :

```
for (int i=0; i<exampleList.size(); i++) {
    String s = exampleList.get(i);
    for (int j=i+1; j<exampleList.size(); j++) {
         String other = exampleList.get(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i agree with @Eran answer traditional for loop but i give my try with iterator

```
    List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    Iterator<String> iterator = exampleList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int start=exampleList.indexOf(iterator.next());
        List lst = exampleList.subList(start,exampleList.size());
        for(int i=0; i< lst.size() ; i++)
            System.out.println(lst.get(i));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stream's skip()` as well , makes for good looking code.

```
List<String> coreModules = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D"));
    for(int a=0;a<coreModules.size();a++){
        coreModules.stream().skip(a).forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
    }
```

Though requires java 1.8,but looks elegent.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is the doc for `stream` which has many such useful filter.